# stripe checkout webhook with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am trying to hit the correct Stripe webhook endpoint for my Laravel API.The Laravel is deployed on heroku, and I have that URL listed as an endpoint in stripe: https...herokuapp.com/api/stripe_webhook.

Current code:

StripeController.php

```php
use Stripe;

public function stripe_webhook()
    {
        $stripe_webhook_secret = env("STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET");
        $payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
        $sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
        $event = null;

        try {
            $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent(
                $payload,
                $sig_header,
                $stripe_webhook_secret
            );

        } catch(\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
            // Invalid payload
            return response(["invalidPayloadErr" => $e], 400);
            exit();
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
            // Invalid signature
            return response(["invalidSigErr" => $e], 400);
        }
        // Handle the event
       
        // HERE, I just want to see the event first before I handle it further. Still can't see this returned response in the Stripe dashboard. 
        return Response::json([ 
            'event' => $event
        ], 201);
    }
```

api.php

```php
Route::post("/stripe_webhook", [StripeController::class, 'stripe_webhook']);
```

VerifyCsrfToken.php

```php
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        "/stripe_webhook",
    ];
}
```

However, I am seeing generic 500 errors for every Stripe webhook event in the dashboard. What seems to be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What are those 500 errors telling you? What are you server logs telling you? A 500 error is most likely either due to Stripe being unable to reach your server/endpoint, or your server hitting an unhandled exception. Please share more detail about what you've been able to find so far via debugging.

Comment: There are no details listed on the 500 errors in Stripe's dashboard. I am trying to add echo statement logs in heroku, but they don't seem to be working. Here is an example of one log I get - 2023-05-11T17:28:07.680302+00:00 app[web.1]: ... - - [11/May/2023:17:28:07 +0000] "POST /api/stripe_webhook HTTP/1.1" 200 11349 "-" "Stripe/1.0 (+https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)

Comment: To try to add echo statement logs in Heroku, I added         'single' => [
            'driver' => 'errorlog',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
            'replace_placeholders' => true,
        ], in logging.php. But still, the echo statements don't show up in heroku logs

Comment: _"There are no details listed on the 500 errors in Stripe's dashboard."_ - of course there aren't, Stripe could only list any information your server gave it in response here in the first place - and 500 errors usually deliberately do not contain any _details_ about the error, because that might give valuable information to a potential attacker. You should check your error logs on heroku.

Comment: Right, I have figured it out. The problem was that I needed to configure my logging.php to send echo statements to the activity log in heroku. Did this by setting >>  'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stdout'), AND BY SETTING >>     'channels' => [

        'stdout' =>[
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stdout',
            ]
        ], ] Thanks